# Read only file system after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, read-only

I recently upgraded to 22.04
It seems that my file system cannot be accessed anymore.
I get a read only file system error message when trying to chown -R my home directory

`more etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7ad80332-310a-49d0-8985-e7dfa83ee62d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=21AF-3E9A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4E0EE4AF0EE490EF /home auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
//192.168.168.82/PAL    /media/NAS/PAL cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,c
redentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users   0   0
//192.168.168.82/PIERRE /media/NAS/Pierre cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=077
7,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users    0   0
//192.168.168.82/video  /media/NAS/Video cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users     0   0
//192.168.168.82/Audio  /media/NAS/Audio cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users     0   0
//192.168.168.82/photo  /media/NAS/Photo cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users     0   0
//192.168.168.82/FRANCOIS   /media/NAS/François cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,file_mo
de=0777,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users  0   0
//192.168.168.82/THOMAS /media/NAS/Thomas cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=077
7,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users    0   0
//192.168.168.82/MATHILDE   /media/NAS/Mathilde cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=7,uid=pierreannelaure,dir_mode=0777,fil
e_mode=0777,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,users  0   0
```

`sudo ls -l home`:

```
total 20
-r-------- 1 root root   24 juil.  4  2020  bblocks.txt
dr-x------ 1 root root 4096 nov.   6 18:46  mathilde
dr-x------ 1 root root 8192 nov.   8 07:14  pierreannelaure
dr-x------ 1 root root 4096 mars  25  2019 'sauvegarde PC'
dr-x------ 1 root root 4096 oct.   9 21:56  thomas
```

`sudo chmod u+rw home/pierreannelaure`:

```
chmod: modification des droits de 'home/pierreannelaure': Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement
```

Which is French for "read only file system"

Comment: @Nmath, update as requested

Comment: What is the filesystem for `/home`?  
Run `mount|grep home` to show it.
The below has `auto` as filesystem, so it's unclear:
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/4E0EE4AF0EE490EF /home auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`
To change ownership, you can use `chown -R user:group home/pierreannelaure`